# Azure AD force reauthentication for digital signatures

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, digital-signature

I have an application in which the execution certain actions within the system requires the user to perform a digital signature (i.e. re-enter the user credentials) for them. I want to implement this using Azure AD (B2C) OIDC SSO. My plan was to redirect to the authorization URL, with the OIDC parameters `prompt=login` and `max_age=0` (inspired by [this article](https://hajekj.net/2017/03/06/forcing-reauthentication-with-azure-ad/) from 2017), but this does not appear to be supported by Azure AD anymore, as I get the following error message when trying it:

> *AADB2C90120: The max age parameter '0' specified in the request is invalid. Max age must be an integer between '900' and '86400' inclusive.*

An authentication 900 seconds would not be recent enough by a long shot, to guarantee that the user has re-authenticated for the action that required a signature. Can one get around the 900 seconds restriction somehow? Is there some other way to approach this problem?

Comment: Have you checked if you have given time diiferently  in keep me signed in ,if you have enabled keep me signed in  >[sessionbehavior - AADB2C](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-kmsi-for-a-user-flow)  and also check in custom policies: Ex: <SingleSignOnScope="Tenant"KeepAliveInDays=" "/> 
 <SessionExpiryInSeconds>0</SessionExpiryInSeconds>  in user journey behaviours. also can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596862/how-to-force-re-authentication-between-asp-net-core-2-0-mvc-web-app-and-azure-ad) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using prompt=login is sufficient, as soon as the user lands on the authentication page with this param, the session cookies get destroyed, so that article implying it’s not enough doesn’t apply anymore.

Comment: You can't guarantee that the user lands on the authentication page though. If a malicious actor intercepts the network traffic or uses something like cURL, they can still delete the parameter without their session cookies getting destroyed.

Answer (score -1):

Not securely/confidently. AAD B2C doesn't support `max_age=0`, and `prompt=login` can be bypassed if you get the redirect URL and remove `prompt=login` before navigating to it (e.g. using curl).

B2B is easier to bypass `prompt=login` (let the browser navigate to the URL, delete `prompt=login` and refresh the page). However, B2B supports `max_age=0`, which can't be bypassed.

Okta has a [great description of the limitations of `prompt=login`](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/max-age-reauthentication).

Comment: The question was about AAD B2C, and it does support `prompt=login`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-authentication-requests

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT It supports it, but it can be bypassed. I just verified this with a test application and clarified my answer.